# Join two tables using date condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two fact tables on Biquery, that i want to join using the id if the datestart is between dateCreate and (dateCreate+10)

Table A

| id | dateCreate | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2548 | 2020-02-05 | smith |
| 6005 | 2020-03-02 | paul |
| 5485 | 2020-03-02 | mitch |
| 5435 | 2020-02-04 | nancy |
| 2485 | 2020-07-05 | milo |
| 2285 | 2020-12-06 | jenif |

Table B

| id2 | datestart | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2548 | 2020-02-20 | dev |
| 6005 | 2020-05-09 | it |
| 5485 | 2020-04-15 | dev |
| 5435 | 2020-02-10 | it |
| 2485 | 2020-09-20 | law |
| 2285 | 2020-12-08 | hr |

If A.dateCreate < B.datestart < (A.dateCreate + 10days)
then count= count+1 else 0

here is the wanted result:

```
| id |dateCreate| name |datestart | job  |
|----|----------|------|----------|------|
|2548|2020-02-05| smith|2020-02-20| dev  |
|6005|2020-03-02| paul |   NULL   | NULL | 
|5485|2020-03-02| mitch|  NULL    | NULL |
|5435|2020-02-04| nancy|2020-02-10| it   |
|2485|2020-07-05| milo |  NULL    | NULL |
|2285|2020-12-06| jenif|2020-12-08| hr   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select a.*
from a left join
     b
     on b.id2 = a.id and
        b.datestart > a.dateCreate and
        b.datestart < date_add(a.dateCreate, interval 10 day);
```

BigQuery sometimes has problems with non-equijoins, but I think this will work.